# Couchbase: How to create JsonObject from a java Object

Tags: java, json, couchbase

How to easily convert/parse the Java Object into a JSON object that is a instance com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject?

I tried to do this:

```
import com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class MyClass {

@JsonProperty("filed")
private String filed;

public MyClass(String filed) {
    this.filed = filed;
}

public String getFiled() {
    return filed;
}
```

and run this lines with imports:

```
    import com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyClass test = new MyClass("a");
    JsonObject node = mapper.convertValue(test, JsonObject.class);
```

and I get:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "filed" (class com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "names"])
     at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject["filed"])
at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2759)
at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2685)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `JsonObject` in Couchbase is meant as a very basic API to work with JSON, close to a `Map`: you `put` simple values to it, you `getString`, `getInt`, etc... from it.

Note that only a limited set of types are accepted in a JsonObject:
null, String, Integer, Long, Double, Boolean, JsonObject or JsonArray.

If you want to store domain objects, for now the best supported way is to marshal them to JSON strings (using your prefered flavor of Jackson, GSon, etc...) and store and retrieve them using the `RawJsonDocument`.

Example to get a JSON string from the database:

```
RawJsonDocument doc = bucket.get("myKey", RawJsonDocument.class);
String jsonValue = doc.content();
MyClass value = unmarshalToMyClass(jsonValue); //this calls eg. Jackson
```

edit: the trick below doesn't work that great (eg. problem converting longs)

<s>but here's a trick to do what you want to do: there's a preconfigured Jackson `ObjectMapper` that you can use in `JacksonTransformers.MAPPER`!</s>

Comment: In my code I used: JsonObject node = JacksonTransformers.MAPPER.convertValue(test, JsonObject.class); instead of: JsonObject node = mapper.convertValue(test, JsonObject.class); and it worked.

but Long doesn't work in this way...
I get : -621171454  instead of 1425307970818

Comment: ah so this trick is not working that good eh... but it wasn't really the intended use anyway. editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple library on top of the Java 2.x Couchbase Client which allows to perform CRUD operations synchronously, as well as asynchronously (through RxJava).

It shows how to use Jackson to serialize / deserialize the beans stored on Couchbase.

The project on GitHub:
https://github.com/jloisel/reactive-couchbase